# Functional template programming instead of inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, functional-programming

I'm currently working on a piece of code in C++11:

```
class A {
public:
    //.. generic public methods which call updateInternalState from time to time ..
private:
    void updateInternalState();
    B internalState;
};
```

Now I want to have several versions of class A which are all identical except for the updateInternalState() method, which is to vary and has atleast 3 different versions, doing different things and might have even more in the future. This sounds almost like a good place to use inheritance with a base class, but I'm wondering if there is a template-metaprogramming version for this, e.g.:

```
#include <functional>
template <std::function<void()> updateInternalState>
class A {
public:
//.. generic public methods, which call updateInternalState from time to time ..
private:
    B internalState;
```

Then I would only have to define the functions somewhere else and explicitly instantiate the versions of A that I want.

I think the biggest problem is that the updateInternalState function needs access to the private members of A. I'm thinking this could be solved by declaring it as a friend of A, or by storing a member of type std::function and assigning the the template argument to it.

Does anyone have experience with such approaches and any recommendations?
Is it a terrible idea and should I just go back to inheritance (which I do not really want, since the rest of the project is written in the generic programming paradigm.)

Comment: They have different functionality, what is your requirements?

Comment: Sounds like you have two classes: a container and a contained object that should know how to update its internal state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be a full academic answer :-)

First remark: What you want to do simply makes no sense!

Step by step:

You can use function pointers as template parameters as this:

```
using FUNCPTR_T = void(*)();


template <  FUNCPTR_T f >
class A {
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        (*f)();
    }
};

void f1() { std::cout << "f1" << std::endl; }
void f2() { std::cout << "f2" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    A<f1> a1;
    A<f2> a2;

    a1.DoSomething();
    a2.DoSomething();
 }
```

But if you want to pass a parameter to your function, which is a class pointer ( this ), you need to define a function pointer which represents this like:

```
using FUNCPTR_T = void(*)(!!!POINTER_TO_THE_CLASS!!!);
```

But this class itself is a template which takes a pointer to a function which has a parameter which is a pointer to a class which takes a pointer to a function .... // endless recursion!

So your attempt simply fail at the point as you are unable to give a correct type for the template parameter.

And as already mentioned: Inheritance is much easier and works perfect. Using CRTP is often used to get access to the using class. Using `std::function` is much easier but moves the cost to runtime.

Answer (score 4):

If update function only uses `internalState`, you can simply store `std::function<void(B&)>` as a member, which is passed during construction:

```
class A
{
public:
  template <typename F>
  A(F&& func)
  : updateFunc(std::forward<F>(func))

  void doSomething()
  {
    updateFunc(internalState);
  }

private:
  using UpdateFunc = std::function<void(B&)>;
  B internalState;
  UpdateFunc updateFunc;
};
```

With this method, you can achieve nice flexibility while still maintaining single type instead of whole hierarchy.

Template-based solution may not be a good idea here - you only need to customize a **single function**, but making this a class template will cause to generate the whole class for every different function  used as an argument. The only advantage is that you can specialize (or partially specialize) the logic, but it sounds like you doesn't need that.

Use inheritance or store update function as a member.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a `std::function` and use lambdas: check out this simple class and its use as an example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> // for _getch()

class A {
private:
    int _state;
    std::function<int()> _updater;
public:
    A() : _state( 0 ) {}

    void addUpdater( std::function<int()> updater ) {
        _updater = updater;
    }

    void callUpdater() {
        updateInternalState();
    }

    int returnState() const {
        return _state;
    }

private:
    void updateInternalState() {
        _state = _updater();
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.addUpdater( []() { return 5; } );
    a.callUpdater();
    std::cout << a.returnState() << std::endl;
    a.addUpdater( []() { return 10; } );
    a.callUpdater();
    std::cout << a.returnState() << std::endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Then to keep track of different instances of the same class, instead of inheritance you can use a map `<id, this*>` where id could be an int or a string. Makes for easy look up too. I think this might be better than templates in this situation because if you template this class where only the `function` differs it will generate a whole new class for each function change. Yes it does move things to runtime because of `std::function`, but it appears to be simpler to implement and manage.

Comment: OP asks for function pointer template instead of inheritance and you answer with run time approach with lambda/std::function. I can't see the answer to the question!

Comment: @Klaus he was trying to avoid `inheritance`. I did miss the part at the end when he did mention the whole project is written in the `generic` approach. I can work on that.